# Custom map grid showing township/range in QGIS Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I am trying to create a map layout with the township/range grid labeled around the map. I created a grid with tick marks every 6 miles, but am not sure how to get annotations of each township/range. I have a shapefile of the PLSS grid (vector).  I played around a bit with custom annotation and can get it to display the properties of the PLSS layer (name, etc.), but not the actual attributes where the township/range is stored.

Is there a way to make a geo-referenced custom grid using a vector layer? Would I be able to convert the PLSS grid to raster and do it that way? Not sure what the best approach is.